# Collection interfaces in C#, coming from Java

Tags: java, c#, data-structures, interfaces

In Java, I'm used to declaring collections using the most-abstract interface possible and then constructing them using the concrete implementation that makes sense at the time. It usually looks something like this:

```
public class MyStuff {
    private Map<String, Address> customerAddresses;
    private List<ToDoItem> tasks;
    private Set<Person> people;

    public MyStuff() {
        customerAddresses = new HashMap<String, Address>();
        tasks = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();
        people = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
}
```

This allows me more flexibility to change a collection's implementation later when all I really depend on is the high-level interface (i.e. I need something to store key-value pairs, or something to store ordered data), and it's generally considered a standard "best practice" in Java.

I'm just starting to program in C#, though, and I'm not sure if there's an equivalent practice for C#'s collections hierarchy. Collections in C# differ from collections in Java in several ways: `Collection` is a concrete type, the `ICollection` interface exposes similar methods to Java's `Set` while the `ISet` interface specifies a lot more features, and the key-set or value-set of a `Dictionary` is not an `ISet`, to name a few. Does it make sense to do something like this in C#?

```
public class MyStuff {
    private IDictionary<String, Address> customerAddresses;
    private IList<ToDoItem> tasks;
    private ISet<Person> people;

    public MyStuff() {
        customerAddresses = new Dictionary<String, Address>();
        tasks = new List<ToDoItem>();
        people = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
}
```

Or are there different "standard" interfaces and implementations to use for such collections? Should I be using `ICollection` and `Collection` in place of either the `Set` or the `List`? I'm tempted to use the C# classes and interfaces that "look closest" to the Java ones I'm used to, but I'd rather use the setup that better fits with C# paradigms and standards.

Comment: This looks perfectly sensible to me.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning, most generic collection type classes implement IEnumerable. This interface is the driving force behind LINQ to Objects and is extremely powerful for manipulating sequences of things.

Comment: As additional info, use `IEnumerable` instead of `IList` to make it immutable. Moreover, `IEnumerable` support input (implicit cast) from array of object and other collection such as `List`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is the interface to use.  It is the most basic interface available for collection type objects.  `IEnumerable<T>` is able to be used in `foreach` loops.  It also contains a number of quite useful extension methods, which allow you to do anything from convert it to a list by calling `ToList()`, filtering results by calling `Where(x => { //filtering functionality }` and all sorts of other things.

The other interface to use is `IDictionary<U, V>`, which is the interface to use for dictionaries.  `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is probably the most useful of the standard concrete dictionary types as it is designed (funnily enough) for concurrency.

Whatever you do, avoid using `List<T>` outside of local variables.

The other thing to note is that `LinkedList<T>` does not implement the `IList<T>` interface.

Comment: Keep in mind that calling `ToList()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` will enumerate the object. (this has some impact on performance)
If you need LINQ often, it may be better not to use an `IEnumerable<T>`, but directly use a `List<T>`

Comment: @Stephen Why should `List<T>` be so strictly avoided outside of local variables?

Comment: @TimothyGroote: Why? `List<T>` is not lazy, and the Linq methods called on a `List<T>` object operate on the underlying `IEnumerable` anyway, so what difference does it make?  Seems like `IQueryable` might be a better choice, if Linq is needed downstream.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you're right, my mistake. should have read more. oh well, the more you learn ;)

Comment: One gotcha: An `IEnumerable` can only safely be enumerated *once*, and may be expensive to enumerate multiple times even when safe to do so.  Thus, I usually avoid `IEnumerable` fields and members.  A class could use a [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) (or the corresponding interface), if you need to go a step further and promise not to modify your collection.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `ICollection` and `Set` is that `ICollection` represents an arbitrary collection of items, while `Set` and `ISet` represent mathematical sets, e.g. no duplicate items and items have no defined order. .NET's version has more methods, because those operations are expected from mathematical sets. The reason why `IDictionary` doesn't implement `ISet` is most probably because then `KeyValuePair<Key,Value>` must have defined proper equality, which would transitively require `Value` to have defined equality. But `IDictionary` only requires equality to be defined for `Key` and not `Value`.

Also you should learn about the [Difference between List(T) and Collection(T) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398903/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-t-and-collectionof-t)